# direct access to HDD

Tags: c++, windows, mbr

I want to print out boot sector using code below, but there is mistake.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;
short ReadSect
   (const char * _dsk,    // disk to access
   char *&_buff,         // buffer where sector will be stored
   unsigned int _nsect   // sector number, starting with 0
   )
{ 
DWORD dwRead;   
HANDLE 
hDisk=CreateFile(_dsk,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
if(hDisk==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // this may happen if another program is 
already reading from disk
{  
   CloseHandle(hDisk);
   return 1;
}
SetFilePointer(hDisk,_nsect*512,0,FILE_BEGIN); // which sector to read

ReadFile(hDisk,_buff,512,&dwRead,0);  // read sector
CloseHandle(hDisk);
return 0;
}

int main()
{
char * drv="\\\\.\\C:";
char *dsk=" \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0";
int sector=0;
int b = 1;

char *buff=new char[512];
ReadSect(dsk,buff,sector);
if((unsigned char)buff[510]==0x55 && (unsigned char)buff[511]==0xaa) cout 
<<"Disk is bootable!"<<endl;
else printf("%02hhX\n",(unsigned int)(unsigned char)buff[511]);

printf("\n");
while (b<513)
{
  if (b%16==0)
     printf(" %02hhX\n",(unsigned int)(unsigned char)buff[b-1]);

  else
     printf (" %02hhX ",(unsigned int)(unsigned char)buff[b-1]);
  b++;
}
getchar(); 
}
```

Instead of printing hexadecimal digits of boot sectors, microsoft visual studio prints out stream of "CDs". What is the mistake and how to fix the problem? Can anyone help?

[Photo of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOHoK.png)

Comment: You should check if all your function calls succeed. For example, `ReadFile` might be failing, in which case `buf` is just uninitialized memory ([which MSVC initializes to `0xCDCDCDCD...` or some other value for debug builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new)).

Comment: I checked the value of _buff in ReadFile and buff in ReadSect using debugger in MSVC and it shows a stream of unknown signs. After converting it into hex value, it showed CDCDCDCD...as output, which means that ReadFile or ReadSect doesn't work...

Comment: That's not what I meant by making sure all your function calls succeed. For example, [`ReadFile` returns a `BOOL` where `TRUE` means success and `FALSE` means failure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx). You should be checking the status of all your function calls to see if they return any errors.

Comment: I checked function call for ReadFile, it returns true. But hDisk returns 0xffffffff, program goes through if condition and closes handle. What is considered as INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE? 0xffffffff is obviously invalid handle value and matches if condition...

Comment: GetLastError() function returns 6, which means INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is `0xffffffff` (for 32-bit systems). FYI, If `CreateFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, you don't need to close the (invalid) handle. Trying to close an invalid handle doesn't actually make sense. If `CreateFile()` is failing, you should check the value of `GetLastError()` immediately after it (before calling other functions).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, start it as Administrator

remove space from

```
char *dsk=" \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0";
```

must be

```
char *dsk="\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0";
```

And, if you use char *dsk, make modification in:

> hDisk=CreateFile(_dsk,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);

must be: 
    CreateFileA (......)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;
short ReadSect
(const char * _dsk,    // disk to access
    char *&_buff,         // buffer where sector will be stored
    unsigned int _nsect   // sector number, starting with 0
)
{
    DWORD dwRead;
    HANDLE
        hDisk = CreateFileA( _dsk, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    //CreateFile()
    if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // this may happen if another program is already reading from disk
    {
        CloseHandle(hDisk);
    return 1;
    }
    SetFilePointer(hDisk, _nsect * 512, 0, FILE_BEGIN); // which sector to read

    ReadFile(hDisk, _buff, 512, &dwRead, 0);  // read sector
    CloseHandle(hDisk);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char * drv = "\\\\.\\C:";
    char *dsk = "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0";
    int sector = 0;
    int b = 1;

    char *buff = new char[512];
    ReadSect(dsk, buff, sector);
    if ((unsigned char)buff[510] == 0x55 && (unsigned char)buff[511] == 0xaa) cout
        << "Disk is bootable!" << endl;
    else printf("%02hhX\n", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)buff[511]);

    printf("\n");
    while (b<513)
    {
        if (b % 16 == 0)
            printf(" %02hhX\n", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)buff[b - 1]);

        else
            printf(" %02hhX ", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)buff[b - 1]);
        b++;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

[image: photo of output]

[WinAPI Unicode and ANSI functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714546/winapi-unicode-and-ansi-functions)

Comment: It works! You helped me a lot! Thank you, Михайл! Спасибо большое!