# Cannot fix an "invalid handle" error in WinAPI when trying to do anything requiring it

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks, windows-console

I am trying to play around with WinAPI to be able to manipulate the console, mostly just be able to write whatever I want, wherever I want without having to rewrite the whole console. I remember that I once got it to work earlier but that was long ago and I seem to have lost that code... whoops.

Anyway, I remember, that I succeeded with much less effort than what it is taking me now.

I am using [this MS Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/) for reference and I remember using it earlier, successfully.

Right now, there is truly only a couple of lines that I am trying to get to work:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hndl = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hndl == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Invalid handle, error " << GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    long unsigned int *chars_written = new long unsigned int;
    if (!WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hndl, "mystring", 8, {20, 30}, chars_written))
    {
        cout << "Could not write, error " << GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is the console window displaying "Could not write, error 6" and then ending the application.

Error 6, according to [System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) is "the handle is invalid".

What am I doing wrong? I must be missing something.

It seems to be important that I am trying to work in Code::Blocks.

BONUS: I tried MS Visual Studio with the full WinAPI SDK (some important parts seem to be missing in Code::Blocks) and, while the main problem is the same, the functions in MS Visual Studio don't seem to all fit the official reference I am using, e.g. [WriteConsoleOutputCharacter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute) requires an LPCWSTR as its 2nd argument instead of a LPCSTR as mentioned in the source and as works in Code::Blocks. [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types)

Edit: I found that WriteConsoleOutputCharacter is a macro actually, and is defined differently between Code::Blocks and MS Visual Studio, as two different, existing in both versions functions: WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA() and WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(), which sadly, is not mentioned in the MS Docs.

Thank you in advance,
Maurice.

Comment: The Win32API has for a lot of functions actually two flavors - an 8 bit character flavor and a wide character flavor. The `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` is actually nothing else than a macro which expands to `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA` or `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW` depending on another certain macro define.

Comment: Yep, thank you very much, I have noticed slightly earlier but it's good that you've confirmed. These macros are also inconsistent, sometimes leading to the A version and sometimes to the W version.

Comment: I personally prefer to use only the functions (ignoring the macros) i.e. explicitly use the `A` or `W` suffixed identifier. (Actually, I try to prevent Win32 API at all, relying on C++ standard lib. but this doesn't work always and PC/Windows is our main delivery platform.) ;-)

Comment: While I got your reply I googled and found this: [SO: WinAPI Unicode and ANSI functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33714546/7478597).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()` requires a wide string as argument, while you're passing a normal string `"mystring"` as argument. To make it a wide literal, you just add the letter `L` as a prefix - e.g: `L"mystring`". And the program is giving you an error because the handle you're retrieving is an **input** handle (`STD_INPUT_HANDLE`). Meanwhile, if you want to output to the console through a handle you need to retrieve an **output** handle (`STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`).

Comment: can I do both? Also, I read that all the WriteConsoloeOutputCharacter() function needs is the GENERIC_WRITE attribute which is always given by GetStdHandle()

Comment: Yes, you can do both, but you would need to create a handle yourself. You can do this by using the CreateConsoleScreenBuffer() function, with its first parameters being GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, which will give you ability to both input and output. Then you have to set it as the active console screen buffer with the function SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer() function.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly, that it will flush my console window and use it in a sort of "new layer", instead of creating a new window?

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. You can have multiple console screen buffers, but only the active one will be the one shown in the console.